# Regroup usings in one

Tags: c#

In C++, I can have a foo.h like that

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"
```

And if I include foo.h in another file, I can use everything that is in a.h, b.h and c.h without having to import them each time

Is there a way to do something similar in c#?

Something like regrouping

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
```

and every using that I always use in one namespace

Comment: if you're talking about `using` *directives*, the answer is no.

Comment: @DLeh yes, I edited my question for clarity

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/24512894/526704

Comment: `Using` directives are NOT the same thing as `#include` in  C or C++. `#include` is for including a header file in your source file. `Using` is for importing namespaces. It is more similar to C++'s `using namespace` directive. And there is nothing at all like it in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately with using directives this is not possible.